# Как убрать элементы в html5 input-ах в Chrome

Tags: html, css, html5

В Chrome при наведении курсора на input-ы type="date" и type="time" появляются дополнительные элементы для редактирования данных в поле. Как их убрать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Осталось только понять как вы будете отображать пользователю список дат, если убрать управляющий элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.superstyle::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.superstyle::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="superstyle" />
<input type="time" class="superstyle" />
```

[Клац](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#inputelement)

Comment: можно еще прибить `-webkit-clear-button`, раз уж инпут исковеркан :-)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko эт [можно](http://jsfiddle.net/kzjc8Lr4/) =)